# write string on sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game with a goat that walks a small rode and you needs to tap it as many times as its number, but i don't know how to write the string. Does anyone know?

I need a code like this:

```
var baloonImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ballong")

goatImage.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(startLocGoatX), CGFloat(startLocGoatY))
goatImage.name = goatName

goatImage.text = "5"

self.addChild(goatImage)
```

Does anyone know how to make the text? And if you know; how can I change it?

Comment: Are you looking for SKLabelNode? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKLabelNode

Comment: Add an SKLabelNode as a child of the goatImage.

Comment: Do you know how to save information inside the sprite?

Comment: You can store data using the `userData` property of [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add SKLabelNode.

```
var node = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Futura Medium")
    node.text = "Hello world!"
    node.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    node.fontSize = 20
    node.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
    self.addChild(node)
```